# How to query previous items of a given criteria

Tags: python, django

Here is the model

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ShootingAttempt(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='shooting_attempts')
    is_scored = models.BooleanField()
    point = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
```

The implementation:

```
jordan = Player.objects.create(name='Michael Jordan')

attempt1 = ShootingAttempt(player=jordan, is_scored=False)
attempt2 = ShootingAttempt(player=jordan, is_scored=False)
attempt3 = ShootingAttempt(player=jordan, is_scored=True, point=3)

attempt4 = ShootingAttempt(player=jordan, is_scored=False)
attempt5 = ShootingAttempt(player=jordan, is_scored=True, point=3)
attempt6 = ShootingAttempt(player=jordan, is_scored=True, point=3)
```

Now how can i query the previous `is_scored=False` if a given **ShootingAttempt** *where pk=5 assumed for attempt5* by Player named `Micheal Jordan`? This will yield the result of: `[attempt4]`

*Means jordan has 1 miss before successfully dig 3 points in 5th attempt*

If the given `ShootingAttempt` where `pk=3` *(attempt3)* this will return

```
[attempt1, attempt2]
```

*Means that Jordan has 2 misses before successfully dig the first 3 points*

And if `pk=6` is given it will return nothing because **there is no** `is_scored=False` **between the last** `is_scored=True` and the `pk=6` (attempt6)

*Means that jordan has no miss of before digging another 3 points*

**Every shooting attempt may miss and i would like to get the last misses of every successful attempt.**

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the steps I would prefer.

Get *id* of the `is_scored=True` `ShootingAttempt` instance you want. Say id1

And you could get another `is_scored=True` `ShootingAttempt` instance using `.filter(id__lt=id1).aggregate(id2=Max('id'))`
this will return you **{id2: some_id}** which has `is_scored=True` and is below the id1.

```
id2 = ShootingAttempt.objects.all().filter(id__lt=id1).aggregate(id2=Max('id'))['id2']
```

Finally you could - `.filter(id__gt=id2).filter(id__lte=id1)` which will return queryset with `False`s and the last `True`.

Comment: This is exactly what i want let me test it

Comment: You could filter player as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order_by` in your query.
For example:

```
last_false = ShootingAttempt.objects.filter(is_scored=False).order_by('-created_at')[0]
```

The filter part chooses those objects with score "False" and after that, those are ordered in descending mode, finally choosing the first element (`[0]`).

You can also nest your filter by player in a similar way:

```
last_false = ShootingAttempt.objects.filter(player=jordan).filter(is_scored=False).order_by('-created_at')[0]
```

Edit:

If you want *all* the previous attempts having the id of the attempt, you can also filter by `pk`, using `__lt`:

```
last_false = ShootingAttempt.objects.filter(player=jordan).filter(is_scored=False).filter(pk__lt=<shootingattempt>).order_by('-created_at')
```

Comment: I mean to get is all the previous is_scored=False of the given shootingattempt

Comment: Since this will only get the last is_score=False.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer and im very sorry for not making it clear. what i want is to get the previous ShootingAttempt instances of a specific pk where `is_scored=False` but not before the previous `is_scored=False` of another  `is_scored=True` record

Answer (score 0):

Work Around.

```
attempts = ShootingAttempt.objects.filter(player=jordan)[:pk]
n = len(attempts)
actual_attempts = [] if attempts[n-1].is_scored == True else 
[attempts[n-1]]
n -= 1
while n and attempts[n-1].is_scored == False:
    actual_attempts.append(attempts[n-1])
    n -= 1
actual_attempts = actual_attempts[::-1]
```